# Implement Register/Unregister-Pattern in C++

Tags: c++

I often come accross the problem that I have a class that has a pair of Register/Unregister-kind-of-methods. e.g.:

```
class Log {
public:
    void AddSink( ostream & Sink );
    void RemoveSink( ostream & Sink );
};
```

This applies to several different cases, like the Observer pattern or related stuff. My concern is, how safe is that? From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307547/determine-object-identity-from-a-reference-to-a-superclass) I know, that I cannot safely derive object identity from that reference. [This approach](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/372) returns an iterator to the caller, that they have to pass to the unregister method, but this exposes implementation details (the iterator type), so I don't like it. I could return an integer handle, but that would require a lot of extra internal managment (what is the smallest free handle?). How do you go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are safe unless the client object has two derivations of ostream without using virtual inheritance.

In short, that is the fault of the user -- they should not be multiply inheriting an interface class twice in two different ways.

Use the address and be done with it. In these cases, I take a pointer argument rather than a reference to make it explicit that I will store the address. It also prevents implicit conversions that might kick in if you decided to take a const reference.

```
   class Log {
   public:
       void AddSink( ostream* Sink );
       void RemoveSink( ostream* Sink );
   };
```

You can create an RAII object that calls AddSink in the constructor, and RemoveSink in the destructor to make this pattern exception-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage your objects using smart pointers and compare the pointers for equality inside your register / deregister functions.

If you only have stack allocated objects that are never copied between an register and deregister call you could also pass a pointer instead of the reference.

You could also do:

```
typedef iterator handle_t;
```

and hide the fact that your giving out internal iterators if exposing internal data structures worries you.

Comment: Smart-pointers are used for shared ownership of objects, which is not the case here. Also, I think what was discussed in the other question I reference applies to smart-pointers as well.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, smart pointer are not the same as shared_ptr, so ignore that part of my comment.

Comment: And the answer was posted in the other question as well. As long as you compare pointers of the same type (say ISink) everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

In your previous question, [Konrad Rudolph posted an answe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307547/determine-object-identity-from-a-reference-to-a-superclass/1307564#1307564)r (that you did not accept but has the highest score), saying that everything should be fine if you use base class pointers, which you appear to do.